# What is this unkillable process and how can I deal with it?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

My (Linux Mint MATE) computer has been running slowly for awhile, but I couldn't figure out why: it seems the slowness was coming from my CPU being overtaxed, but the System Monitor didn't show any app responsible.

Eventually I tried using `top` and saw this:

```
 882461 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.3   0.0  48:11.39 kidle_i+ 
 882465 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.3   0.0  48:11.41 kidle_i+ 
 882466 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.3   0.0  48:11.53 kidle_i+ 
 882467 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.3   0.0  48:11.56 kidle_i+ 
 882468 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.3   0.0  48:11.68 kidle_i+ 
 882462 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.0   0.0  48:11.10 kidle_i+ 
 882463 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.0   0.0  48:11.46 kidle_i+ 
 882464 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S  50.0   0.0  48:11.71 kidle_i+
```

I can't find any reference to a "kidle_i+" process anywhere on google, and neither `sudo killall kidle_i+` or killing manually by process ID (eg. `sudo  kill -9 882461`) seems to have any effect. `killall` tells me `kidle_i+: no process found`, while `kill` seems to work ... but doesn't kill the process.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on with this process, and how I can either A) understand why it should be running, or B) stop it from running?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/584636/kidle-inject-causing-very-high-load You might want to check your temperatures with `sensors` before killing or disabling this service

Comment: Thank you!  The command from that answer (`sudo systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled`) seems to have killed the process, and my system is operating normally again.

Comment: The + means the name is cut off. The `k` prefix suggests this _may_ be a kernel thread.

Comment: FWIW, you _might_ be assuming that your discovery of `kidle_i+` is somehow related to your overall slowness. Keep in mind one thing might not be related to another. If you ask me, this is not the cause off your slowness because `kidle` could just mean “kernel idle.” I would recommend backing away from the assumption that these process are the cause when they might just be symptoms.

Comment: Thanks, but it was definitely the cause: as soon as I ran that `systemctl` command to kill them my computer started running normally again.  I don't know what that process does, but it seems to be more of a "consume massive CPU resources when idle" process than just a "the kernel is idle so I'll run" process.

Comment: @machineghost After reading the thread I've linked you **should** know what this process does. It probably protects your CPU from overheating!

Comment: Maybe that's it's intended purpose, but as the author of that very question explained, there's a bug in the kernel making it misbehave, and disabling this process had no ill effects on his machine (even months after).

Comment: @machineghost - If there is a bug, then the issue will just repeat, until it's patched.  I have no doubt it's already been patched.

Comment: As you can see for yourself, the bug is both confirmed, and un-fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1389077.  However, the answer mashuptwice provided does offer a way to make the "fix" permanent.  The tricky part is determining whether it's a bug or a legitimate issue (if your laptop's brand isn't the one from the bug).

Comment: @machineghost actually pretty easy to find out. Check `sensors`, if your CPU temperature is way below 85°C and powerclamp is injecting anyways, it is malfunctioning or it could be triggered by power profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `kidle_i+` is a shortened (for `top`) form of `kidle_inject`.  This process normally runs when your system is overheating, slowing down your CPU usage so you don't overheat your processor.

However, it can also run due to a bug (eg. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1389077).  To determine which, you can use the `sensors` command.

See https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/check-cpu-temperature-on-linux/ for full instructions on installing the command, but it's basically `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`, `sudo sensors-detect`, pressing `enter` a lot, and then finally running `sensors`.

`sensors` will tell you the current temperature of your CPU, and how close it is to critical heat.  If you're not sure you can try running `sudo rmmod intel_powerclamp`.  This will disable the `kidle_inject` processes, but you need to carefully watch `sensors` afterward to see if your CPU temperature is increasing.

If it is you should restart immediately (to get `kidle_inject` back and give your computer a second to cool off).  If this happens, you probably have a broken computer fan, a ton of dust, or some similar physical problem.

If your CPU temperature doesn't rise however, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584636/kidle-inject-causing-very-high-load) has instructions for disabling it permanently (although again, you should watch `sensors` for awhile to ensure heat isn't an issue before disabling things permanently).